# Order for a single product getting placed and cancelled automatically along with all orders

Tags: product, magento-1.8, orders, cancel-orders

There is no issues in placing order from the website. But in Magento admin panel along with each order a default product is shown as ordered and cancelled. This is making me confused. How to solve this issue.

***Embellished Flare Abaya with Tight Sleeves - CS037-XL
SKU: CS00037-XL
Canceled    AED375.95

AED375.95
Ordered 1
Canceled    1
AED375.95
AED0.00 0%  AED0.00 AED375.95***

Adorned Abaya with Soft Black and White Wool Layer - CS007
SKU: cobracs00-L
Size
L
Ordered AED400.00
AED400.00

Ordered 1
AED400.00

AED0.00 0%  AED0.00 AED400.00

The one which is in bold is not ordered from website. But still it is shown in the Magento dashboard. This is the case for each new orders. The product showing as ordered and cancelled is the same in all orders.

Comment: Do you install any custom extension for order related functionality into website? If yes then try to disable that extension and then check.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - No, not installed any custom extensions recently. The site was working perfectly fine before. The problem got noticed last week only.

Comment: I am not asking recently, but try to disable all custom extension one by one and then check.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - tested the site by disabling the custom extensions. But the issue still persists.

Comment: How to check the magento code base if there is something that adds above extra details into database along with each order placement?